# Accessing Two dimensional fixed byte array

Tags: c#, pascal

I am struggling with two dimensonal fixed byte array use.I have to Convert A pascal Char type with the similiar size in C# .I have to have some character values in this array.

I am declaring this like public fixed byte C10VAFT[14*20];

I dont know whether this array is simply a one D array of size 280 or it is a two dimensional array reason being I am not able to get my intensional values becoz I get series of Byte.

Thanks
Ashok

here the the code.
this is a pascal structure

```
CREC10 = RECORD
         C0RT    : INTEGER;
         C0KEY1  : INTEGER;
         C10VAFT : ARRAY [0..13] OF PACKED ARRAY [0..19] OF CHAR;
         C10VH1H : PACKED ARRAY [0..19] OF CHAR;
         C10VH2H : PACKED ARRAY [0..19] OF CHAR;
         C10VH3H : PACKED ARRAY [0..19] OF CHAR;
         C10MPE1 : PACKED ARRAY [0..14] OF CHAR;
         C10MPE2 : PACKED ARRAY [0..14] OF CHAR;
         C10MPE3 : PACKED ARRAY [0..14] OF CHAR;
         C10MPR1 : PACKED ARRAY [0..14] OF CHAR;
         C10MPR2 : PACKED ARRAY [0..14] OF CHAR;
         C10MPR3 : PACKED ARRAY [0..14] OF CHAR;
         SPARE2  : PACKED ARRAY [0..61] OF CHAR;
         C10CP   : INTEGER[4];
         C0BRRP  : INTEGER[8];
         END;
```

blow is the replica struct in C#. i am stuck with the ** element

```
public unsafe struct CREC10
    {
        public short C0RT;                     
        public short C0KEY1;
        **public fixed byte C10VAFT[14*20];**
        public fixed byte C10VH1H[20];
        public fixed byte C10VH2H[20];
        public fixed byte C10VH3H[20];
        public fixed byte C10MPE1[15];
        public fixed byte C10MPE2[15];
        public fixed byte C10MPE3[15];
        public fixed byte SPARE2[62];
        public UcsdInt4 C0CP;
        public UcsdInt4 C0BRRP;

    }
```

Comment: can you add some code you have so far?

Comment: I'd like to help but you've not asked a real question yet. You did not show the pascal data structure, nor describe how you use it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added the structure.

Comment: And details of what you are to do with it please. For a start I have to say I am sure you don't need unsafe or fixed. Are you trying to do pinvoke to a DLL?

Comment: infact a 2d char array in pascal is having string type values ,which in need to retrieve in C# from the DTA file , after making changes into those values have to save back to .DTA file. My purpose is to get byte stream for particular index then convert those bytes to string but i am not able to get those bytes, thats the porble,

Comment: Yes there is a DLL which interfaces with .DTA file.to be very frank m not much familar with safe and unsafe context too as i m pretty new to C# as have been working in Pascal.

Comment: You still are not quite clear to me. Is the C# code going to call a DLL, or is it going to get a byte stream, and decode that into a structure? OK, since I now see a comment where you say "I don't know what p/invoke is", it is surely the latter. You get a byte stream containing that structure, and need to convert it to a C# structure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I do call A dll from C# code and get a byte stream. then to decode it into particular structure.

Comment: So you are using p/invoke.

Comment: if that is it I do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native answer to your question is that you cannot make a two-dimensional fixed array. The compiler does not let you. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) says:

> Unsafe buffers are always vectors, or one-dimensional arrays.

If you are to continue to use `unsafe` and `fixed` then you would need to either:

1. Declare 14 separate fixed byte arrays.
2. Declare a single fixed byte array of length `14*20` and then index into it manually.

The indexing would be something like this:

```
int arrIndex(int elementIndex, int charIndex)
{
    return (elementIndex*20) + charIndex;
}
```

This does illustrate the syntactical hurdles that you have to jump over to use fixed size buffers.

---

I think that what you are actually doing is taking a byte stream laid out as per your Pascal record, and wanting to transfer that into a C# structure. And possibly back again. In my opinion it is a mistake to try to use the same layout in C#. The compiler does not want you to do so. Don't fight it. Use a natural C# layout for the structure and provide mappings between the natural C# layout, and the on-disk layout.

The first point I want to make is that you categorically do not need nor want to use `unsafe` or `fixed` here. Both of those just make your life harder than it needs to be.

First of all I'm going to assume that you have your raw data in a C# `Stream` instance. If it comes from a byte stream then you would make a `MemoryStream`:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

But it doesn't really matter. It can be a file stream. It just wants to be in a stream.

Then you define a C# structure to receive the data. This does not need to match the rigid layout of the Pascal data structure. Use native C# types. For instance:

```
public struct CREC10
{
    public int C0RT;
    public int C0KEY1;
    public string[] C10VAFT;
    public string C10VH1H;

    public static CREC10 FromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I've not defined all the fields. Just enough to give you a flavour. And I've also added a static method that can make a new one from a stream. That would be implemented like this:

```
    public static CREC10 FromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        CREC10 result;
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            result.C0RT = reader.ReadInt32();
            result.C0KEY1 = reader.ReadInt32();
            result.C10VAFT = new string[14];
            for (int i=0; i<result.C10VAFT.Length; i++)
            {
                result.C10VAFT[i] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(20));
            }
            result.C10VH1H = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(20));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This does assume that there is no packing in your structure. It does look as though that would be the case. And I'm also assuming that your integers are 4 bytes wide, but perhaps for this somewhat elderly Pascal compiler that is not the case. In any case, I believe that you know the binary layout of the data structure and can iron out these details.

And you can write a matching function to copy the struct to a stream using the same format.

If you try to stick with your rigid Pascal layout in C# you will find it excruciatingly difficult to actually work with your data in C# code.

Comment: But this sturcture is going to exceed the limit of 512 byte size and in such case data read from the data base is  not going to be  approprate as i do it from fixed of functions interface by DLL.

Comment: @user3079498 Your in-memory representation does not need to match the on-disk representation. You will find it appallingly hard to work with your data if you force it to be held in C# in the same layout as your legacy Pascal structure.

Comment: @user3079498 My answer now tells you that you cannot use a 2D fixed buffer. I am still convinced that your approach is wrong, but if you want to persist with it, my answer tells you how to.

Comment: What I think we are missing is some understanding of why you feel compelled to match the binary layout in your C# code. I suspect that you've just settled on that without fully understanding the consequences. Fixed size buffers are a total nightmare to use. But perhaps there is a really good reason why you do need to match the binary layout. In which case please tell us. What I'm getting at is that the first part of my answer for sure answers the direct question that you asked. We could just stop there, but I think we can do better. I would like to make sure that you get the best solution.

Comment: I realy appriciate your help in this matter. thanks.You are pretty right about the fact abt my understanding of using FIxed buffers but i am stick with it due to my legacy system and the existing code has handled it in this way only.. So I was bound to that

Comment: Hey david, this is one of the technique my existing code has used. and now I hope you solution working for sure. thanks a lot for having that much patience for my quenstion.

Answer (score 4):

By using this decalaration C10VAFT[14*20]  you are getting an array  of   3920 and you are  getting  an  array of byte because the difference between char and byte in  .net is that 
byte=8bits and  char =2bytes (16bits) which is different from  PASCAL where  A byte and a char are the [same thing](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Char)

in C# a Multidimensional array is declared like  this

```
 char[,] array = new char[14, 20]
```

or [A jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

```
 char[][] array = new char[14][] ;
```

Comment: You can also declare with `char[,] array = new char[int size, int size]`

Comment: What you show is not multi-dimensional array. It is called `jagged array` both are different

Comment: sorry I  updated my answer but it would work  either

Comment: @JulieShannon  specificaly I have to read some UCSD pascal .DTA ,where a similar structre which is having a 2D array of size [14][20].Here in C# I have to have a array of similiar memory size which could be posible with taking a Fixed byte 2D array.so thats where I am struck.Hope fully I converyed my problem this time :)

Comment: Char is wrong here. These are bytes surely. And it is remiss of you not to discuss the use of fixed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan IN my code fixed byte array is working fine but when its two dimensaional array ,I am struck with.

Comment: @JulieShannon Why should he mark it as the answer. It sure doesn't look like the answer. The question is still unclear. We need more details.

Comment: could you  add your explanation  as a comment if you see anything  else  I will appreciate this  :)

Comment: @user3079498 Yes it is very unclear. Are you doing binary interop with pinvoke? Or do you just want an equivalent structure in you C# port?

Comment: I have just answered the first post the OP he just updated his answer and I think that he is  doing a portability not Pinvoke

Comment: if i Get answer to How a Two dimensional fixed byte array is used in C#,then I think I will be able to deal with my prob. I dont know what Pinvoke mean .

Comment: @user3079498 No, you absolutely do not want to use a 2D fixed byte array. Instead of deciding that you know how to find the best solution, please can you tell us what your problem is, and let us tell you the best solution. Since you are still learning C# then you are not in a position to come up with the best solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have fixed sturcture size of 512 byte in pascal, I have to have a struct of same size in C# as well, this structure holds data for some particular record. THe work i have done yet in dealing with structures, taking Fixed byte to replace a char data type worked fine.this is again a array of char, so i thought going with fixed bytes will work.

Comment: Why do you need to use the identical 512 bytes structure in C#? I think you should address any further discussions with me to comments to my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My flat file database, file structure is such like its having records in size of 512 bytes. So whatever data I read from the data base or need to write to data base i need to pass a structre of this size to a DLL function. this is the contraint with me other wise i might have gone with your solution at the first place.

Comment: You said you were not using p/invoke. Now you say you are. If you just need the 512 bytes, use a byte array. If you need to operate on the data in C#, then your 512 byte structure is going to make it impossible.